# llenar un arreglo de cantidad N, con un ciclo while

Tags: c++

quiero llenar un arreglo con un while, pero no me da, alguna sugerencia, tengo esto... Quiero llegar del 1 al 10, y lo muestre
agradeceria su ayuda, saludos amigos de la comunidad.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int i=1;
    int a[10];
    while(i<10){
        i++;
        a[i]=a[i+1];
    
    }
    cout<<a[5];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Por favor no hagas preguntas diciendo cosas como *"pero no me da"*, por favor cuéntanos que comportamiento inesperado está teniendo tu código o qué errores te aparecen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No se si esté bien, es la primera vez que hago algo con c++ pero lo hice así:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(void){
    // Your code here!
    int entrada = 0;
    int a[10];
    while (entrada<10) {
        a[entrada]=a[entrada++];
        std::cout << "|" << entrada;
    }
}
```

Y eso me dió esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tienes el mismo error que el autor de la pregunta, y es al hacer esto: a[entrada]=a[entrada++]; le estás asignando a un elemento del array, el valor del siguiente elemento de ese array. Si éste no tiene un valor válido dará error. Además, a la hora de mostrar, muestras los valores de la variable "entrada", no los del array. Mas o menos habría que poner: a[entrada]=entrada+1;std::cout << "|" << a[entrada];entrada++; dentro del bucle. Saludos!